# display image and signature pad in js and send output as email

Tags: javascript

not familiar with it hence asking here. I have a working signature pad solution here: https://plnkr.co/edit/WEnlwvuwngceK1GC52iu?p=info

html:

```
<div id="canvas">
  Canvas is not supported.
</div>
```

js (I believe somewhere here?):

```
return {
    //public functions
    capture: function (){
            var parent = document.getElementById("canvas");
            parent.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "";

            var canvasArea = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvasArea.setAttribute("id", "newSignature");
            parent.appendChild(canvasArea);

            var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

kudos to https://github.com/zetakey/signsend.
an image (consent.png stored on the server) should be displayed right above this signature pad - it goes the signature.js file, but how?. in the end, both image and signature should be sent as email (upload_file.php). can someone help? thx

Comment: I've used [signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) to do it, you can send the dataURL of the signature to the server and then put it in the `src`attribute of an `img` tag in an html formatted mail.

Comment: thanks Chocolord for your input. question: it's completely out of question that a)  you have a working solution for this somewhere (where one can check, e.g. plunker) and b) you share it here, is it? thanks anyway.